# How can "e.target.id" be used as index in for loop?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm looking at these lines in old `javascript` code:

```
tempIndex = window.event.srcElement.parentElement.id;
tempIndex = e.target.id;
```

`tempindex` is being used in this way in for loop:

```
for(var i = tempIndex; i < all.length; i++)
```

Noobie Understanding of `id` tag is must start with a letter

How can this be used in for loop?

Comment: id doesnt have to start with a letter a class does

Comment: you might need to do tempIndex = parsenInt(tempIndex,10); to make sure it is a number. But I don't think it will break anything if left off.

Comment: Modern browsers support ids that start with numbers. But if you want it to start with a string, than just use a prefix. Question is a bit unclear what the real problem is, more code would have cleared it up. A lot of times, do you really even need the id? Most times, there is no reason to have it.

Comment: An id could be just a number but it is not a good idea, nor is it a good idea to use it as an index and iterate from there forward through the entire DOM - their could be thousands of elements, and ones of interest may occur earlier in the DOM. Class names and container objects should be use to narrow down iterations.

Answer (score 2):

If you were to do this properly and want to use the id as a value id suggest using data-attributes

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

```js
const elem = document.querySelector('div');

console.log(elem.id) // can be a number but cant be used in css
console.log(elem.classList[0]) // can be a number but cant use in css


// but you're right they cant be used as query selectors. 

try {
  console.log(document.getElementById('1'), 'but you can select with getElementById')
  console.log(document.querySelector('#1')) // cant select with id
} catch (e) {
  console.log('failed to select')
  // "Error: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#1' is not a valid selector.
}

try {
  console.log(document.querySelector('.1')) // cant select with id
} catch (e) {
  console.log('failed to select')
  // "Error: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '.1' is not a valid selector.
}
```

```css
.1 {
  color: red;
  /* this wont do anything */
}

#1 {
  color: blue;
  /* stil wont do nowt */
}
```

```html
<div id="1" class="1">Hello, world.</div>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('#1')` can't select but `document.getElementById('1')` can.

Comment: yeah that's correct but the idea is querySelector matches how css selects items and I think that's where OPs confusion came from. but a good spot! I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If possible the value of IDs should have no other meaning than identifying a DOM element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

> This attribute's value is an opaque string: this means that web author must not use it to convey any information.

If your HTML is a source for JavaScript functionality, you might be better off using `data`-attributes:

```js
var element = document.querySelector('[data-iterator]');

if (element) {
  var iterator = Number(element.getAttribute('data-iterator'));
  for(var i = 0; i < iterator; i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="something" data-iterator="20">
</div>
```